# Using Python to create SPSS custom dialog

Tags: python, spss, customdialog

I am trying to use Python in SPSS custom dialog. 
My question is how to capture the input value(s) from the UI of the SPSS custom dialog into a variable in Python?
I've tried something like `var_python=%%thisvalue%%` but this returns an error.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add quotation marks. Also don't forget to add BEGIN PROGRAM and END PROGRAM command.

e.g.:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.

this="%%item_294%%"
print this

END PROGRAM.
```